# SQL Server : convert function won't work on datatype time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Been struggling with this one for hours.

I have a set of data that looks like this:

Table name: `TEST_1`

`log_date` and `log_time` are both currently `varchar(200)`

Current formatting example:

- `log_date = 20131004`
- `log_time = 113052:123`

I want to convert the `log_date` and `log_time` to a better format (especially the time)

Here is my code

```
INSERT INTO TEST_2(log_date, log_time, process, log_type, detail_msg, decision_msg)
   SELECT  
      CONVERT(date, log_date, 111), CONVERT(time, log_time, 114), 
      process, log_type, detail_msg, decision_msg
   FROM TEST_1
```

Now the `log_date` conversion seems to work fine but I get this error when it tries to convert `log_time`

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I've tried changing the datatype to `varchar` and it doesn't give the error but it also doesn't convert anything.

Help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The time convert expects format of 11:30:52:123 not what you have

Comment: Please tell what this value signifies `113052:123` .. that is what is the hour / min /sec  etc parts

Comment: do you know what the time units are? or know what '113052:123' means in a typical 24 hour notation? 6digits:3digits is new to me at least; Maybe you could do select max(log_time) to give us an idea of the maximum value currently held?

Comment: hi guys, 113052:123 = hh:mm:ss:msss on a 24 hour clock. I would like it to be 11:30:52:123 or something similar

Comment: select MAX is 224114:672

Comment: great that max value seems to confirm that string manipulation should remain valid i.e. 22:41:14.6720000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a way... it gets down to string manipulation, I'd like to see more values really.

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(date, log_date, 111) AS log_date
, cast(
       left(log_time,2)
       + ':' + substring(log_time,3,2)
       + ':' + substring(log_time,5,2)
       + right(log_time,4)
       AS time)                AS log_time
FROM test_1


CREATE TABLE Test_1
    ([Log_date] varchar(200), [Log_time] varchar(200))
;

INSERT INTO Test_1
    ([Log_date], [Log_time])
VALUES
    ('20131004', '113052:123')
;

|   LOG_DATE |         LOG_TIME |
|------------|------------------|
| 2013-10-04 | 11:30:52.1230000 |



  [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1dff0/6
```

Comment: Thankyou, I didn't even think about going along the substring route!

Answer (score 0):

While `20131004` is considered to be a valid `varchar` value for `datetime` conversion, `113052:123` isn't.

Since you specify 114, its format should be something like `11:30:52:123`.

Give this a try:

```
   CONVERT(
     time,
     substring(log_time,1,2)+':'+
     substring(log_time,3,2)+':'+
     substring(log_time,5,2)+
     substring(log_time,7,4), 
     114)
```

Comment: Thanks GEO - I think what I'm looking for is how to get the that end state of 11:30:52:123.

Comment: Thankyou, I didn't even think about going along the substring route!